# PROBLEM: pandas.DataFrame.mean deleting columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I'm working with Google Colab to create a neural network. I've imported the dataset and created the dataframe, but when I use the function `mean` it deletes last columns (from the column "res_x4trap"). What I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow import feature_column
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Data collection
filepath = '/content/netdataset.csv'  
data = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=";")
data.set_index('INDEX')

test_df = data.sample(frac=0.2, random_state=1337)
train_df = data.drop(test_df.index)

train_df = train_df.reindex(np.random.permutation(train_df.index)) # shuffle the training set

# Calculate the Z-scores of each column in the training set and
# write those Z-scores into a new pandas DataFrame named train_df_norm.
train_df_mean = train_df.mean()
train_df_std = train_df.std()
train_df_norm = (train_df - train_df_mean)/train_df_std

# Examine some of the values of the normalized training set. Notice that most 
# Z-scores fall between -2 and +2.
train_df_norm.head()
```

BEFORE:
[image]

AFTER:
[image]

Comment: What's the full warning message that appears twice?

Comment: @9769953 FutureWarning: Dropping of nuisance columns in DataFrame reductions (with 'numeric_only=None') is deprecated; in a future version this will raise TypeError.  Select only valid columns before calling the reduction.
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:4: FutureWarning: Dropping of nuisance columns in DataFrame reductions (with 'numeric_only=None') is deprecated; in a future version this will raise TypeError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into that same problem, it turns out one of my columns was of type object because there were problematic entries, so pandas didn't know what to do when calculating the mean so it just deleted it.

So check the dtype of the columns using
`df.dtypes`